# Javascript getting keypress "Enter" Event on Input Type Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Javascript getting keypress "Enter" Event on Input Type Text

I have 3 text inputs, 1 dropdownlist and 10 rows.

Row 1 will have identifier of _1 for the 3 text input and dropdown follow by _2 for row 2.

What I wanted to achieve is:

```
Textfield1 ------>   left_1
Textfield2 ------>   center_1
Textfield3 ------>   right_1
DropdownList ---->   dd_1
```

When I press enter on `left_1`, I want to change the enter event as sort of "tab" to `center_1`, while if I do enter event at `center_1`, it will tab to `right_1`.

If I do enter event at `right_1`, it will go to the next row `left_2`.

Problem is normally if you press "tab" at `right_1`, it will focus to `dd_1`

The next key issue is, I got a submit button in the form, if I press enter at any of the form, it will just submit the form. I tried before disable the enter using checking the eventcode and prevent Default but doing so, I still unable change my enter to focus on the text field as mention above

[image: My Picture to describe question]

[JsFiddle on my Question](http://jsfiddle.net/kL2ntc2u/4/)

I need to able to go to row 2 at the last input for the first row upon enter.

Comment: unclear what you asking..

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @JoeFrambach I updated my issue with a picture, my code is a bit messy, but what I wanna achieve is similar to what David posted below, but I want to able to go to next line on enter too

Comment: @JoeFrambach JsFiddle of my issue http://jsfiddle.net/kL2ntc2u/4/

Comment: @AnantDabhi JsFiddle of my issue http://jsfiddle.net/kL2ntc2u/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, if the textboxes are all siblings in order, e.g.

```
<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
```

With nothing inbetween, then you could just do something like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == "13")
    {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }

})
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kL2ntc2u/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle, but if the last sibling on press enter want to go to next row 1st input, how do I make this possible

Answer (score 1):

you can use keypress event
for expample :

```
var input = document.getElementById('test');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
console.log(e.key);
if( e.key == 'Enter' ) {
...
}
});
```

Comment: There a submit button in my form, will it be able to disable the Submit Button so it work as tab instead